# How do I generate a texture with texturetool that pvr2atf will accept?

Tags: ios, air, starling-framework

The Adobe docs for the new ATF SDK (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashruntimes/articles/atf-users-guide.html) state that the pvr2atf file is specifically designed to let you convert textures created with texturetool into ATF textures. I have a PNG texture (with transparency), and when I create an ATF with it directly, I get some odd artifacts around the edges of the non-transparent pixels. When I create a PVRTC texture with texturetool from the same source image, the preview generated by texture tool looks great. So, I was hoping I'd then be able to convert that into a clean ATF that I could then use on iOS in a Starling app.

However, when I use the texture created by this command:

```
texturetool -e PVRTC -o atlas0.pvrtc -p atlas0-preview.png -f PVR atlas0.png
```

pvr2atf complains:

```
Illegal pvrtc texture type.

(Hint 1: In PVRTexTool CL type needs to be OGLPVRTC4)
(Hint 2: In PVRTexTool UI select the 'OpenGL ES2.0' tab in the 'Encode Texture:' dialog and select 'PVRTC 4BPP')

Conversion failed!
```

I've tried a few different options to the texturetool, but have not managed to generate a single texture that pvr2atf doesn't have a problem with. Has anybody managed to do this? These tools are very new, and there's not a lot of info out there, aside from what Adobe has written (and in some cases their docs directly contradict the result of the tools, such as in the case of when transparency is supported).

I am downloading PVRTexTool now to see if I have better luck there, but I need this eventually to be automatible so needing a GUI tool would be a major bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters download the Imagination PowerVR SDK from [here](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp)

Dont use texturetool, it isnt updated as much as this tool which is from the developers of PowerVR:

In here you will get a GUI version of the texture packing tool called PVRTexTool, thats much easier to use. In here you can open your PNG and then manipulate it including the format the texture is set to. Click the box at the top with the 3 yellow arrows pointing down to see compression formats

It would appear you need to use PVRTCII 4bpp which defines a compressed texture 4 bits per pixel for OpenGLES 2.0. This also allows you to see all the other formats and have a play around if that format doesn't work.

Comment: I really need a command line tool as mentioned above. I think the PVR folks might have a command line tool in their package, but I wasn't able to get a texture out of their GUI tool that look good enough... although to be fair I've concluded that's just a limitation of the format: compressed textures look bad.

Comment: This tool is the same as the command line tool, trust me i explored every avenue when i started OpenGLES. These tools are not new however, i have bene using them for well over 2 years now and they had been around way before i started using them. The compression of .pvr determines its quality. I increase the quality by using a larger texture size usually 1024 x 1024 or 2048. I use this for everything and i dont loose any quality too. So its either air or something you have missed.

Comment: My project is a bit unusual, I'm using flump (https://github.com/threerings/flump) with source art that is composed of sliced up photographs. That being said, I expected lossy compression to impact me less than it might a normal 2d flash project, but even with mipmaps and trilinear smoothing, I can't get around the fact that users are looking closely at the art and it just doesn't look nearly as good as it does with the source PNG textures. I might try using larger source art, but I can't get around how tight this art needs to be on the device.

Comment: Anyway, marked this answered. Contrary to Adobe's docs, it does seem to be true that texturetool just can't be used for this task, and it does look like PVR would do the trick if compressed textures were appropriate for my project. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: One last note: ATF seems to only accept/use PVRs with 4bpp, so you're already cutting your color space in half. That alone is enough to impact the quality of a flash project's art. Hopefully ATF will support a wider range of PVR in the future, making this more feasible for AIR projects.